# Result set with triple union

Tags: sql, union, sybase, sap-ase

lets say I have a simplified `table` with 2 Columns:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
| a    | c    |
| b    | d    |
+------+------+
```

Now, I want a result set where I can wirte my header in line 1 and all distinct values of `Col1`and `Col2` in the follwing lines like this:

```
Header
a
b
c
d
```

while it works fine with only one Column:

```
select 'Header'
union
select Col1
from table
```

suprisingly it does not work with more than one union:

```
select 'Header'
union
select Col1
union
select Col2
from table
```

fails. Who knows why and can tell me how to achieve what I want?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `union` does not guarantee ordering.  Try this:

```
select col
from (select 'Header' as col, 0 as ordering
      union
      select Col1, 1
      from table
      union
      select Col2, 1
      from table
     ) t
order by ordering;
```

Comment: Thanks also to you! I am curious how the ordering works with union, i.e. does it order just randomly? It seems to work fine for me also withour ordering

Comment: @WilliFischer . . . Ordering is not declared unless you specify an `order by` clause.  It is that simple.  In practice, `union` has to do a lot of work to remove duplicates, and the returned ordering depends on them method for finding duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select 'Header'
union
select Col1
from table
union
select Col2
from table
```

You are missing the FROM clause in your second SELECT statement.

Comment: This answer. A tweak to consider. Do you really want 'Header' is a data row? You can make it the field name instead with "select Col1 as Header from table UNION Select Col2 as Header from table ..."

Comment: Thanks. @Bill: I know Union all is faster, but my table will never be so big to make a difference. Also, I do not have to worry about grouping here. Also, I want 'Header' as a data row, because for some strange reason the results have to be exported and distributed to several people in csv format, but we do not save headers, so it has to be the first data row.